# Proving that $f(z)\neq \frac{z}{z+1}$ in $D_1(0)$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, analyticity

Suppose $f$ is analytic in $D_r(0)$ for some $r>1$. I want to prove that $f(z)\neq \frac{z}{z+1}$ in $D_1(0)$. This is how I tried to prove this.

Assume $f(z)= \frac{z}{z+1}$ in $D_1(0)$. Now define $a_n=-1+\frac{1}{n},n\in \mathbb{N}$.
Then $a_n \in D_1(0)$.

Thus $f(a_n)=\frac{a_n}{a_n+1}$. So $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(a_n)$ should exist as $f$ should be continuous at $-1$. But, $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(a_n) \rightarrow \infty$$
This is a contradiction so the assumption is false. For some reason I feel like this is flawed. Can someone suggest a better answer or improve this? Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: If you by $D_1(0)$ mean the ${\it open}$ unit circle, then actually the function $\frac{z}{z+1}$ is analytic there.

Comment: Yes but it is analytic in a larger disk than that too

Comment: No, it is not analytic on $D_r(0)$ if $r>1$, since it has a singularity at $z=-1$. In fact, that function is analytic on $\overline{\mathbb{C}}\setminus\{-1\}$, having single pole at $z=-1.$

Comment: Yes that is what I have tried to prove in this

Comment: I have tried to get a contradiction @Mher as i have clearly mentioned in my question and answer

Comment: sorry, if I misunderstand, so all you're asking is the alternative way of getting contradiction ? since since you've already got one.

Comment: @Mher That's okay. I need an alternative only if what I have done is wrong

Comment: @Mher If there is an alternative please do enlighten me anyway :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18965/discussion-between-mher-and-heisenberg).

Comment: First, your way of getting the contradiction is quite right. Second, an alternative way can be that since the function is rational function then it it has a singularity at zeros of denominator.

Comment: But the thing is the limit lies outside the unit circle where the function may not take the form z/(z+1) so getting the discontinuity there is sort of an issue

Comment: @Heisenberg The identity theorem. If $f(z) = \frac{z}{z+1}$ for all $z\in D_1(0)$, then by the identity theorem we have $f(z)=\frac{z}{z+1}$ on every connected open set in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{-1\}$ that intersects $D_1(0)$ where $f$ is analytic. In particular, that holds on $D_r(0)\setminus \{-1\}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I am aware of that just need to get my method verified

Comment: Then I don't understand your question. You know that if $f$ is analytic on $D_r(0)\setminus\{-1\}$ and $f(z) = \frac{z}{z+1}$ on $D_1(0)$, then $f$ has a pole at $-1$, so cannot be analytic on $D_r(0)$.

Comment: I have tried to get a contradiction to show that f cannot be z/(z+1) in the unit disk

Comment: What my SUPPOSITION says is that f is analytic in $D_r(0)$ including -1

Comment: Indirect proof. Assume that you had $f(z) = \frac{z}{z+1}$ on $D_1(0)$ conclude that $f$ is not analytic on $D_r(0)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Isn't that what I have done given that the method is not wrong

Comment: Yes, it is. My first comment was a reply to your "But the thing is the limit lies outside the unit circle where the function may not take the form $z/(z+1)$ so getting the discontinuity there is sort of an issue" to inform you that it is not an issue that the limit (of the $a_n$) lies outside the unit disk [and why].

Comment: Thanks but this maybe stupid to ask say I never knew the identity theorem. Then is my explanation sufficient ? @DanielFischer

Comment: Yes, it is. Boiled down to the essentials, if $f$ is analytic on $D_r(0)$, then it is in particular continuous on $\overline{D_1(0)}$, hence bounded there, and a fortiori bounded on $D_1(0)$. But $\frac{z}{z+1}$ is unbounded on $D_1(0)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks but again my problem is that the sequence I constructed has a limit outside the unit disk which I have used to prove the discontinuity. Is this correct? Is there anything I can add to it to make it betteR?